# How to use shared html in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a shared html in the basic angular4 page,
i want to use a tag

```
  <search-items (search)="filter($event,'q')"></search-items>
```

which should display a text box of search option.

[this is the code iam trying](https://plnkr.co/edit/9fbMEcBj5cJBoywhqNwj?p=preview)

what should i do to remove my errors?

Comment: what errors are you getting please specify them

Comment: you can run the given link, use console window to show the errors

Comment: alot of things were missing , i am able to remove the error . Will post the answer now

Comment: i am just learning things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code yourself : This is your **app.ts**

```
//our root app component
 import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {SearchComponent} from 'search.ts'
import {FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
 @Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: '
 <div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <search-items (search)="filter($event,'q')"></search-items> 
     </div>',
 declare:[SearchComponent]
})
 export class App {
 name:string;
 constructor() {
 this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
 }
 filter(text:string,text2:string){
  console.log("hi")
}
}
 @NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule , FormsModule],
declarations: [ App , SearchComponent ],
bootstrap: [ App ]
})

 export class AppModule {}
```

2nd fix was in search.ts : your search.html was misspelled as search.component.html

Note : Do import FormsModule from @angular/forms whenever you use ngModel in your code

Comment: there is one issue, try entering something and click button and check console.log. after that enter something and click enter. chack console again, you can see function is triggering twice in second case.

Comment: Are you sure ?Because i did exactly as u told and it still fires only once . Can you please debug more and give some more info so that i can help you ?

Comment: did you check the console.log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147780/discussion-between-aakash-uniyal-and-hilda-sonica).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Aakash Uniyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44794313/4512411) here is the new [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Du9Lif?p=preview) with the issue resolved.

You also needed to import FormsModule

```
`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'`
```